# jQuery: Update, by class, all span tags and populate with textarea value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

How can I update all  tags, with class="able", with the textarea value thats
stored in the textarea id="txtholder" class="txtholder field?

In Function Primary I've tried:

```
$('span.able').text($('#Primary.txtholder').val());           FAIL
$('span.able').text($('#Document.Primary.txtholder').val());  FAIL
$('span.able').text($('#txtholder').val());                   FAIL
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Tak.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery Pass textarea value to all class=able SPANs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$('#button1').click (function () {
$('span.able').text($('#Primary.txtholder').val());    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<Fieldset>
<form name="Primary" method="post" action="" >
<font size="2" color="maroon"><b>TEXTAREA VALUES:</b></font><br>

<textarea id="txtholder" class="txtholder" name="txtholder" rows="8" cols="45">
8012,Ms 8012,8012@something.com; 8013,Mr. 8013,8013@somethingelse.com; 8014,Mr. 8014,8014@somethingelse.com; 
8015,Mrs. 8015,8015@somethinggood.com; 8016,Mrs. 8016,8016@something.com; 8017,Ms 8017,8017@somethingelse.com; 
8018,Ms 8018,8018@something.com; 8019,Mr. 8019,8019@somethingelse.com; 8020,Mr. 8020,8020@somethingelse.com; 
</textarea><br>

<input type="Button" id="button1" Value="LOAD">

</Fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<span id="result1" class="able"> </span>
<span id="result2" class="able"> </span>
<span id="result3" class="able"> </span>

<span id="result4" class="baker"> </span>
<span id="result5" class="baker"> </span>

<span id="result6" class="charlie"> </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your last one:

```
$('span.able').text($('#txtholder').val());
```

works ([proof](http://jsbin.com/ekuziy)). (Or if you don't want to limit it to spans [you've said "all tags" in your question text, which could mean a couple of things, but "all span tags" in the title], just `$('.able').text(...);`)

The real problem is with the script you're putting it in. With proper indentation, it's clearer what's going wrong:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#button1').click (function () {
        $('span.able').text($('#Primary.txtholder').val());    
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, you haven't closed the first call to `$`. So it wouldn't matter what you put in there, because the script syntax is invalid. Change that to:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#button1').click (function () {
        $('span.able').text($('#txtholder').val());  // <=== Fix
    });
}); // <=== Fix
</script>
```

Indenting your code consistently can really help prevent these sorts of errors. It's also useful to look at the JavaScript console of the browser to look for errors, and to [use a proper debugger](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) to watch your code run.

Comment: One thing, just to be clear with the first part of the question, `'span.able'` will grab all spans with a class of `able`, to grab all tags you just use `'.able'` :)

Comment: @Nicosunshine: Yeah, I read "all tags" as "all matching elements" (people are pretty imprecise with their language), esp. since the question title says "all span tags", but I've added a note just in case the OP really meant "all tags".

Comment: Pleea excuse my delayed response and THANK YOU sooo much for your prompt one.